# How to trigger event when value deleted from JFormattedField?

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, actionlistener

How can I trigger an event to clear the object value using the method commitEdit() after deleting the value from a JFormattedField using "ctrl+a & delete button"? Currently the change is done only when changing the focus.

Comment: Maybe a `DocumetnListener`?

Comment: You probably want to pass `true` to the [setCommitsOnValidEdit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html#setCommitsOnValidEdit-boolean-) method of DefaultFormatter, which is inherited by DateFormatter and NumberFormatter.